# Difference between C# and Java when converting DateTime to byte array

Tags: java, c#, database, datetime, arrays

I have a Java program that reads each value from a database and converts it to a byte array.  I am currently trying to write an equivalent program in C#.  However, I'm having difficulties with DateTimes.  The Java code and the C# code produce different byte values.

Here is the Java code:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from " + query);
while (rs.next())
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); j++)
    {
        byte[] b = rs.getBytes(j);
        if (!rs.wasNull() && b != null)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
                System.out.print(b[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output for the DateTime **2/19/2016 3:12:21 PM**:

```
-71 -3 65 70 116 -74 -28 64
```

Here is the C# code:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from " + name, conn);
OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        if (rdr[i] != DBNull.Value && rdr[i] is DateTime)
        {
            DateTime date = (DateTime)rdr[i];
            byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes((long)date.Ticks);
            foreach (byte bt in b)
                Console.Write(unchecked((sbyte) bt) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output for the DateTime **2/19/2016 3:12:21 PM**:

```
-128 -72 98 16 63 57 -45 8
```

I am not sure how to get these to match.  According to the Java documentation for ResultSet's `getBytes(int columnIndex)` method, "the bytes represent the raw values returned from the driver".  So it seems that, unlike the standard C# protocol, it is NOT using the ticks value in order to produce the bytes.  This becomes apparent when attempting to translate the byte array back into a DateTime.  Converting `-71 -3 65 70 116 -74 -28 64` into a long gives you `4676062923628608953`.  But that value exceeds the maximum tick value for a DateTime, so it cannot be converted into a valid DateTime.

So how does Java end up with those particular byte values then?

I need a way of converting DateTime to byte[ ] in C# that will ALWAYS have the same behavior as Java's `getBytes(int columnIndex)` method.  **I cannot modify the Java code.**  The C# output must match the Java output.  Is this possible?

Comment: Can you share the Java code that stores the dates in the database?  (Or is it C# code that stores the dates in the database?)

Comment: Little-endian and big-endian confusion?

Comment: Java uses the milliseconds since January 1, 1970. C# uses `Ticks` - one ten millionth of a second, and counts them starting from January 1, 0001.

Comment: `getBytes()` is not defined for non-binary data, e.g. it may return driver-specific data. To get a date value, use `getDate()` or `getTimestamp()`, both of which provides a `long getTime()` method for retrieving the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. You can then convert that to whatever byte sequence you want.

Comment: @Andreas I can't modify the Java code though, only the C#.  Which is a problem.  Obviously the value I got from getBytes() does not represent the number of milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970.  4676062923628608953 milliseconds is 148 million years.   So it sounds like I can't get an accurate number of milliseconds without using getDate() or getTimestamp()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBytes%28int%29) is not defined for non-binary data, e.g. it may return driver-specific data.

> The bytes represent the **raw** values returned by the driver.

It would seem that the particular database / JDBC driver you are using is sending the value as a `double`.

`-71 -3 65 70 116 -74 -28 64` is actually `b9 fd 41 46 74 b6 e4 40` in hex, which is the `double` value `42419.633576388886` in Little-Endian order.

```
byte[] b = { -71, -3, 65, 70, 116, -74, -28, 64 };
System.out.println(ByteBuffer.wrap(b).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getDouble());
```

```
42419.633576388886
```

If you paste that into Excel and format it as `m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM`, you get `2/19/2016 3:12:21 PM`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919641/how-to-convert-a-double-value-to-a-datetime-in-c) for how to convert in C#.

Comment: You are a lifesaver.  Changed my C# code to this and it worked like a charm:  `byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(date.ToOADate());`  Thank you for your help!